# How to setup vscode for debugging when working with Typescript, React, and webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I have followed [the official tutorial from the Typescript website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) and successfully setup a working `Typescript` + `React` + `webpack` application. But the breakpoint I set didn't work when debugging it using vscode. Here is the structure of my code.

```
.
├── dist
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Hello.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Searene <mycityofsky@gmail.com> (https://searene.github.io)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^15.0.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

#### Hello.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }

export const Hello = (props: HelloProps) => <h1>Hello from {props.compiler} and {props.framework}!</h1>;
```

#### index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("example")
);

console.log("the breakpoint is put here");
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello React!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

        <!-- Main -->
        <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Launch.json used in vscode

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I installed the [extension: VS Code - Debugger for Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug). Then run the following command.

```
webpack
```

Two files are generated in the `dist` directory.

```
dist
├── bundle.js
└── bundle.js.map
```

Yes, I do have a `map` file. Then I setup a server in the root directory, which listens to `http://localhost:3000`. I can see that my app is running correctly without any errors or warnings.

[image: my working app]

Then I started chrome with debugging enabled

```
google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Then in vscode, I set a breakpoint in the following line in `index.tsx`.

```
console.log("the breakpoint is put here");
```

and pressed `F5` to start debugging.

I can see that the log is successfully printed in `DEBUG CONSOLE`, but it didn't stop on the breakpoint, it just kept running.

[image]

What can I do to make the breakpoint work in vscode?

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your launch.json? `"sourceMaps": true` and `"outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js" ]`

Comment: Check this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQCYxz_89uE